# Using GIT to keep operational systems up to date

Tags: asp.net, git, smartgit

I'm not a Git novice but also not a guru either and I have a question. We want to create remote repos that appear as folders within our network. The folders will actually contain a large legacy ASP app running in a production manner.

Then we want to be able to make local changes and be able to push commits to these networked repos and thus dynamically update the production application.

We already have the repo on Github and our developers fork that and work locally (we use SmartGit for most day to day stuff).

However (because the app is huge and legacy) we have (prior to using Git) always had a process for copying changed files to the target systems (production, QA etc).

But it dawned on me that we may be able to treat the operational system "as" a repo that's checked out to master. Then (when suitably tested) we want to simply use SmartGit to do a "push to" the operational system and have the changes delivered that way.

I'm at the edge of my Git knowledge though and unsure if this is easy to do or risky.

We don't want to install Git on the operational machine (its restricted to running Windows 2003 - yes I know...) so want to simply treat the remote system just like it was a local folder - with Git installed on our local machines.

Any tips or suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

My tip: don't bother.

You can only push to *bare* repositories. These are such that they only contain the files normally residing in `.git`, with no working directory at all. So you cannot "run" those on the server. You would need to push to a bare repos on the server, and then clone/checkout that bare repos into a non-bare local repos on the server itself (which can be done in a post-receive hook inside git). But as you said, you cannot even install git on the server. So `git push` does nothing for you.

Second option would be to mount the servers filesystem on whatever staging/deployment machine you have, presumably one which you can install git on. Then you can `git push` into a bare repos on that deployment machine, run git hooks, and copy newly pushed stuff into your non-git server filesystem.

Third option would be to package everything up locally, make a tarball (or, I guess, zip-ball...) and just unpack that on the server.

So. Automated, continuous deployment => great idea. Using git => great idea. Directly using `git push`, not so much, mainly due to your constraints.